# how to validate data before we do data mapping or migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, migration, mapping

I have task where i need to move data from one table1 to table2, i have source columns and destination columns but before i move data is it possible to find out is there any data in source column doesn't not fit destination column because of destination field type difference or field length is less like that ?

Like in a scenario i have source column which is char(1) and i am trying to map that column data to int column, here most of rows in source column have integer values but there are some alpha characters in some rows so i want to find out all those rows which are going to fail....the logic should work for all data types.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code find the columns which are different(datatype) between New table and Old table.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,COLUMN_NAME,IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE,
       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,NUMERIC_PRECISION,NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'New_Table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='Table_Schema'
EXCEPT
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,COLUMN_NAME,IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE,
       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,NUMERIC_PRECISION,NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Old_Table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='Table_Schema'
```

Comment: but in my case i cant compare table schema, i want to compare the exact data in source column!! because in some cases i can migrate int column data to varchar data so i cant use table schema to compare data types....